Coolpad Note 3 (8676 I02) Boot Issue on Fastboot
This is the First Display On the Screen When I on the Mobile.

Its Automatically Move to the Second Screen, It Shows Only Up and Down , If I Press The Volume Key, There is No Response From The Mobile
I found this on Youtube, But i am unable to Connect With ABD Shell..
https://youtu.be/stxsRF3v2fE?si=TCtg4hXziZ_BSClK
PLease Help me!!..


Can you navigate up and down using the volume keys?

Sorry but the text on your photos is not readable, it seems to be too bright for the camera to capture it.

Thanks for the reply, on the 1st Image: Up and Down, In the 2nd Image: =>[FACTORY] and =>FASTMMI MODE, I can't Use any Key (Volume Button), Their is No Reaction from the Mobile

Then one possibility could be that one of the volume keys have a hardware defect and are detected by the phone as permanently pressed. On most phones holding vol down at boot is the way to enter fastboot or other manufacturer specific debug download or test modes.

Actually the Volume key is not on the right side, it's on the left, but the Screen shows its on the right.

Did i used a wrong TRWS Recovery??, Or did i damaged the Inbuilt ROM

If I may connect to ADB debug from my system, i can make it work, but I am unable to connect

ADB only works if the system is next to fully booted into the regular system. If the device is in bootloader, fastboot or similar state adb never works. Only some special recovery ROMs allow adb access.
